# Duplicating data in Controller Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to duplicate data with a click of a button, in better terms, trying to reorder a previous order. This is my code

```
$order = Order::find($id);

        $order_details = OrderDetail::where('order_id', $id)->get();

        $reorder = $order->replicate();

        $reorder_details = $order_details->replicate();

        $reorder->save();

        $reorder_details->save();
```

The `$order` data replicates fine, however the `$order_details` data doesnt, as I get this error `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::replicate does not exist.`

Is there a way to duplicate without using `replicate()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `$order = Order::find($id);` returns the first instance (a model) and `$order_details = OrderDetail::where('order_id', $id)->get();` returns a collection. Just have to change it to `$order_details = OrderDetail::where('order_id', $id)->first();` and it will work fine.

To handle multiple order details:

```
$order_details = OrderDetail::where('order_id', $id)->get()->each(function($item) use($reorder){ 
    $newItem = $item->replicate();
    $newItem->order_id = $reorder->id; //If needed, be sure to pass $order if you do 
    $newItem->save();
});
```

Comment: Great! Will that work if there is multiple items with the same id, and if not how could I implement this?

Comment: If you need to replicate multiple details you could use `each()` on the collection after you get it. See my edit.

Comment: @John **note** I think you would need to set `order_id` in each `order_detail` to the replicated order's id. If you simply replicate order_detail it will keep the previous (aka original) order_id

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `__clone()` method which you can implement inside the order class,

Then you can use it like this

```
$order = Order::find($id);
$newOrder = clone $order;

$newOrder->save();
```

Comment: My guess is that this would also duplicate it's primary key, which will give issues when trying to save the `Order` afterwards.

Comment: I think not because you can specify that in the `function __clone()` that you implement inside of the object, you just set the id to null or unset it!